# How to fix error of type “object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()”?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am building a Decision Tree and while fitting x_train and y_train, I am getting this error, can anyone please help?

I have built a model of Decision Tree classifier and I am getting error of "object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()",

Don't know why.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace, as well as a sample of your data

Comment: May be chance to get this error, If you have multiple categories in a single column. Just do encoding and after try it